# Showing particular language is NP-complete

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

How is FLO NP-complete?

Let G be a social network where vertices correspond to people and edges are relationships between people (undirected).

Some pairs of people (who are friends) get married.
We allow polygamy: person a could be married to person b and to person c.
A friend relationship between person x and person y is defunct if x did not marry y, but either x or y married someone else such as person z. The entire social network is said to be flo if every relationship is either a married couple or a defunct friendship.

Let FLO be the language consisting of strings $<G,k>$ such that G is a social network in which k marriages can make the network become flo.

Comment: Try to make an reduction from the Clique problem to FLO. Or from Vertex-Cover problem to FLO

Comment: That seems to be a P problem as finding all non defunct friendship relations is polynomial, as well as all $n$ people involved in them. On marriage can fix two of those people, so you'll need exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ marriages.